# How to document a WCF web-service in a technical spec?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Other than pasting a WDSL in the tech spec, what are the recommended ways to document a WCF web-service before you begin coding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We recently published a WCF based SOAP interface for third parties to integrate against.  For each method we provided the following:

- Method name
- Request example (wire format dump)
- Request parameters explanation
- Response example (wire format dump)
- Request parameters explanation
- Caveats (gotchas)
- History

We also provide the WSDL.  You may want to use Microsoft's [Disco.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs.aspx) for doing this.  See also a related question about [obtaining the WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286657/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-all-of-the-wsdl-files-exposed-by-a-wcf-service).

Answer (score 2):

Document the contract interface as you would document any other interface. Describe the operations, pre-conditions, post-conditions, reasons for throwing a fault, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in case you're using MessageContracts document why you are using them... trust me, you'll wonder why you did it :)

Answer (score 1):

- Describe service endpoints and available protocols/binding. e.g. Https, RESTful?
- Security features, authentication, authorization and encryption.
- Explain the use cases of parameters in operation contract.
- Hosting, IIS, WindowsService or Console application.
- Instancing of the service.