# What is the best way to download all of the WSDL files exposed by a WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

What is the best way to download all of the WSDL files exposed by a WCF service?

For example, the root WSDL file references the following other WSDL files:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:80/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.com"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:80/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://tempuri.com"/>
```

Ideally it would be possible to automate the download so that every time the WSDL changes it would be easy to distribute the files to a customer or incorporate into a document/SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft provide [Disco.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs.aspx) for doing this.

Comment: Sorry being so dumb, but how to download it?

Answer (score 34):

Meanwhile, disco.exe is considered obsolete technology by Microsoft.

You can use  `svcutil.exe /t:metadata` to achieve the same in the WCF age. Additional benefits are support for additional features, eg WS-Policy.

Save schema from URL:

`svcutil /t:metadata http://host/pathtomy.svc?wsdl`

Save schema from assembly, eg in automated build:

`svcutil /t:metadata c:\wcfweb\pathToWcfServiceAssembly.dll`

Comment: Thanks Bernard. Haven't been doing any WCF for a while - do you have a reference? I'll mark your answer as accepted if you can provide one.

Comment: @ThomasBratt Can you clarify what you mean by reference?

Comment: @Bernard he means a link to the MS page that says this is so.

Comment: Hi Thomas and @RegEdit

The disco.exe documentation page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cy2a3ybs(v=vs.100).aspx for its latest version, Framework 4.0, says: 
This topic is specific to a legacy technology. XML Web services and XML Web service clients should now be created using Windows Communication Foundation. 

And svcutil is part of the WCF related tools https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 6):

If you own the service, another interesting option you could explore is using Christian Weyer's [FlatWSDL behavior](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx), which will force WCF to generate everything in a single WSDL document, which should make it a lot easier for you to distribute it.

Comment: The excellent WCFExtras project on codeplex can also be used to generate a single wsdl file. Dead easy to use, find it here - http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple code snippet that makes it possible downloading a WSDL and all the belonging XSD files for offline use (for example for code generation).

**Update**

The blog where the code snippet was shown is not available anymore. Luckily, Pablo Diez created a small project based on my blog post and uploaded it to github. It is available now here: https://github.com/pablod/xsd-downloader

Comment: The link is not outdated - the solution is a good one if you're working in Java.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I either got a 404 or DNS error when trying the link, so I could never read the solution. Site is obviously back up again, so my comment is not valid anymore...

Comment: Link is dead again. Please would you update your answer when possible to include the relevant information as we're [encouraged to do to avoid this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)..