# Generate webservice from wsdl

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

This is maybe a really simple question, but I couldn't locate an answer:

For a client I need to HOST a webservice. The client has sent me a wsdl file that the webservice should 'implement'. How do I go about that? I've generated any number of client-rpoxies but this is the other way around. I can use both ASP.NET 2.0 webservices or Windows Communication Foundation.

Comment: generate WSDL for existing classes = "bottom-up strategy" [versus] generate a class skeleton given existing WSDL = "top-down strategy" (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[wsdl.exe /server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx).

> Generates an abstract class for an XML
>   Web service based on the contracts.
>   The default is to generate client
>   proxy classes. When using the
>   /parameters option, this value is a
>    element that contains
>   "server".

You can do a similar thing with svcutil.exe for WCF- something like:

svcutil.exe thewsdl.wsdl /language:c# /out:ITheInterface.cs (I've not tested this).

Edit- John Saunders makes a good point in his answer to favour the WCF approach- I recommend this too.

Comment: Is it really that simple? I've used wsdl.exe numerous times but didn't know about the /server switch. I'll test and report

Comment: Yeap. WSDL first development is a valid approach- see this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: If you want the result it in C# it is as simple as this: svcutil.exe thefile.wsdl

Answer (score 14):

Actually, you should do this with svcutil.exe, not with wsdl.exe. WSDL.EXE is part of the ASMX web service technology that Microsoft now considers to be "legacy" code, which will not have bugs fixed.

Comment: That's kind of the point. The idea would be to generate code that the manufacturer does not consider "legacy", and where they still plan to enhance it and fix bugs.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call

Answer (score 2):

You can do plenty with that WSDL (wissd'le) file.

From doing the WS Class **manually** to use the **Auto Generated** class from wsdl.exe

let's **imagine** that, for your example, you have this [WDSL](http://www.webservicex.net/TranslateService.asmx?wsdl) (tooked from [WebServiceX.Net](http://www.webservicex.net/WCF/ServiceDetails.aspx?SID=47))

---

to **create a C# auto generated proxy** you go to your command prompt and write:

```
wsdl /language:cs /protocol:soap /out:C:\myProxyScripts http://www.webservicex.net/TranslateService.asmx?wsdl
```

**Note**: inside your C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin folder you will find wsdl.exe or just do a dir /s inside your C:\Program Files\

if you want in **Visual Basic**, just use **/language:vb** or **/l:vb**

> /language:
>       The language to use for the generated proxy class.  Choose from 'CS',
>       'VB', 'JS', 'VJS', 'CPP' or provide a fully-qualified name for a class implementing System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.
>
> The default
>       language is 'CS' (CSharp).  Short form is '/l:'.

This command will put inside your C:\myProxyScripts the auto generated proxy.

if your using the **WSDL file in your computer**, just **change the URL** to your **full path**, for example

```
wsdl /language:cs /protocol:soap /out:C:\myProxyScripts C:\myProxyScripts\myWsdlFile.wsdl
```

**Note:** your Generated proxy will be called the **Service Name**, the one you have specified, in our example, as:

```
<wsdl:service name="TranslateService">
```

I hope this helps you, understand the WSDL, the Auto Generated Proxies and that you can manage now everything in your end to fulfill your client wishes.

Comment: New wsdl versions deprecated `/server`, now is better to use `/serverInterface` (and implement it) Server switch has been deprecated. Please use /serverInterface instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wsdl utility from microsoft to generate the server interfaces and implement them

Here is a short description of the WSDL utility.

> wsdl.exe -
>       Utility to generate code for xml web service clients and xml web
>   services
>       using ASP.NET from WSDL contract files, XSD schemas and .discomap
>       discovery documents. This tool can be used in conjunction with disco.exe.