# Adding web service from another project

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, wsdl

I have a solution (asp.net) that already contains a reference to a web service, now i want to add this web service in a new solution, but the web service now is protected and i cant add it by the normal way. I want to take the code of the web service from the old solution and add it to the new solution. The service is wsdl.

Comment: Host ws in IIS and use url to add reference, instead of adding project to solution

Comment: Sorry but how can i do this if i only have reference to the web service

Comment: what is url of the web service?

Comment: http://41.128.33.6:80/miniOctopusWS/miniOctopus

Comment: use this to add reference in new project / solution

Comment: Unable to connect to the remote server when i do this

Comment: why it is outside your network? is so you have to allow its access in firewall

Comment: no the now i'm not authorized to add it.

Comment: do you have local copy of web service?

Comment: i've a copy of the wsdl, cs,map,xsd,etc files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221121/generate-webservice-from-wsdl

Comment: If you don't have permission to access it, then stop trying to access it.

Comment: No i can open the access for it but it may take long time to contact the providers to open access for my IP and i need to use it now.