# Testing calls to third party webservices

Tags: .net, web-services, unit-testing, mocking

As part of our object CRUD work flow we need to call third party web services. I am trying to find a way to unit test this. Obviously, I don't want / can't call the actual web services as they don't exist yet. I do have the WSDL that they will be using. Does it make sense to make my own "fake" service to match the WSDL and have the app call it or should I look into mocking frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Faking" the service would be creating a mock. The question therefore boils down to, should you use a mocking framework, or should you mock based on the WSDL.

[svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) can be used to [make a service stub out of a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call). So it would be quickest in this case to not use a mocking framework like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). However, if you plan on mocking other things in your app, it might make sense to take the time to learn a Mocking framework and use that.

Comment: WSDL?!  What is this 2001?