# C# API with XSD/WSDL

Tags: c#, api, xsd, wsdl

I'm used to adding a web reference in VS and building an API from there.

I was handed on WSDL document and two XSD documents to build an API from.  How do I go about creating the API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading about the Wsdl.exe tool, which should build the C# classes for you from the Wsdl definition file.

Comment: This requires the SDK to be installed on the computer running VS, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this from the command line:

```
svcutil your.wsdl (or svcutil your.wsdl /l:vb if you want Visual Basic)
```

I got this from basically a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call).

Comment: Yes, it comes with the Windows SDK from what I understand.