# How do I use the WSDL file that I got?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, wsdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)

I need to use a web service in my application.

I have a WSDL for the web service, but I don't know how to use it or how to call and send info to the web service method.

Someone can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181854%28VS.90%29.aspx
"Create a .NET Web Service provider endpoint from a WSDL file."

Comment: I have the same question but I am using Java! I received a WSDL and I don't know what to do and how to use it!

Comment: searching the internet for java wsdl will give you lots of hits e.g. http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf