# Create WCF Service based on Existing WSDL and XSD

Tags: wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

If I use svcutil, I don't think I can generate server side code because all interfaces generated don't have `ServiceContract` attribute and all model classes don't have `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

So what is the best way I can create my WCF service from existing WSDL?

Comment: What do you mean by server side code?  The code for the service?  You can't - svcutil is for generating a proxy for the client to use.  If you're trying to generate a proxy to use by a client, then yes, scvutil can do that from a WSDL.

Comment: See also this answer by marc_s:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/950598/745969