# What is the use of the /serverInterface and /server option for the WSDL.exe tool

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

All, Generally.With the asp.net tool WSDL.exe tool, I think there are three ways to generate asp.net code from the wsdl file.

1. default output to generate client proxy class.
2. generate abstract class code.(add `/server` option)
3. generate interface code.(add `/serverInterface`)

In my understanding the 1 is generating a client proxy class which can help handle the request and response for or from the web services for the client side.

As to the 2 and 3 ,I believe actually they are used to generate code for the server side when you want to implement your own web services from the generated abstract class or interface .

But I am not sure whether my understanding is right . hope someone who is familiar with it can help to verify it . If it is not right, please correct me .thanks.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks your advise +1. I will think about migration from ASMX to WCF. this will be an another problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as John has already said use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) if possible.

You are correct however, the `/server` and `/serverinterface` are used to generate code for the server-side components when you have an existing WSDL document for a web service.

Although for many ASP.Net developers the web service implementation comes first and is used to produce the WSDL it can be that you have an existing WSDL document for a web service that you need to implement in ASP.Net, for example a legacy web service that is being migrated to a new platform.  In this case those two switches are used to help produce a web service which is compatible with the existing WSDL so that clients may use your ASP.Net web service without needing to re-consume the WSDL (which often requires a code change in that client).

I myself have used this feature before to create stub web services for testing purposes when I have the WSDL for a web service however it is not possible to test against the actual web service implementation.

Comment: Right ,  In my scenario, I have to implement a web service which is compatiable with the existing WSDL. that means the client side doesn't need to change any exist code to consume the new created web service. But Since you talked about WCF, I was thinking if there is some tools like wsdl.exe to generate server side code for WCF? thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang See [How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)

Comment: +1 @Justin I see, `svcutil.exe` is the upgraded version of `wsdl.exe` :)

Comment: [how to create a WCF service from a WSDL file using the svcutil.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx). Cheers