# Connecting to web-service without metadata

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to connect to this web-service

https://training-api.temando.com/schema/2009_06/server.wsdl

I have tried to both of "Add Service Reference" and "Add Web References", but in both cases got this error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://training-api.temando.com/schema/2009_06/server.wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>
> The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Is this extra part of URL generically for web services or is specially for WCF?

And what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is download the WSDL file on to your machine and use the `svcutil.exe` tool to generate code directly from the WSDL.

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call) for an example of how this is done.

I believe what you are doing is called WSDL-First development.  A more detailed link on that is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx).