# Ebay API using SOAP in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, ebay-api

I would like to perform these following in Ebay API.
1. GetOrders
2. Add Shipping Fulfillment and Tracking Number to the Order
3. Get Inventory Items

This can be possible using SOAP web service for Ebay API. I'am planning to use `Trading API` and I have tried to add this web service to my VS `http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl` however I've got this error:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

Thanks.

Comment: why is there '/&metadata' at the end of your request? This question and answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221590/connecting-to-web-service-without-metadata

Comment: Have you tried using Trading API in asp.net ?