# Create similar WSDL file to existing WSDL file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web, wsdl

I have a WSDL file for a Web service created in java

I need to create an identical WSDL file  in C#(asmx or WCF doesn't matter) .NET where the only existing web method implementation would be changed but keep the same signature though.

I always have different WSDL files which won't work for the client

**EDIT**
I ended up using WSCF(web service contract first) it seems the only solution out there 
the resulting WSDL with some manual minor modifications seems quite similar to the original file.

Comment: "I need to create an identical WSDL file in C#" does that mean you created the web service in C# as well and want to know how to get the WSDL from the created web service?

Comment: I want to make my WSDL identical to the java WSDL , is that possible? since the client will duplicate the instance and use my WSDL to call the service(he is using typco to communiate with a variety of webservices)

Comment: Sounds like you just need to copy and paste your WSDL. A more clearer explanation is required for us to understand what your issue is atm.

Comment: Ok , I have a WSDL for a web service created in java and I want to create a new webservice in C# similar to the java webservice in all aspects except the webmethod implementation ,,, the constraint here is WSDL of my service must be identical to WSDL of Java webservice ,, I hope it is clear now

Comment: grammar and clarity improvements

Comment: The question here is there a way for me to change a WSDL file to make it identical to an existing WSDL file(soap headers, messages, namespace...Etc)

Comment: So in essence you want to write a wrapper web service in C#, which will produce the same WSDL output, but have no implementation code inside the web methods? One big question: Why? Why not just use the WSDL from your java web service? **What is the underlying requirement**?

Comment: No again , the webmethod in C# would have a different implementation than the one in Java ,,, only the WSDL output would be as similar as possible to the one in Java if not identical

Comment: Then naming the WebMethods the same names, with the same input and output types and property names will generate a roughly similar WSDL, but since you have two different tools that are generating the WSDL, they won't look the same, but will have the same meaning to the consumer

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a little off. I interpret your question as

[How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)