# How to create a mock WCF service in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf-hosting, mockserver

I have a decompiled client that calls a web service, the only configuration parameter is the endpoint url the rest is all in the service class. I wanted to simulate the service that calls starting from his wsdl I managed to do it with a visual studio 2017 web project and adding the .asmx file and implementing the methods from the interface generated by the wsdl. Basically I created a mock as a rule is made in soapui.

The question is: how can I do the same thing using a WCF project?

I Have followed this Post: 
[How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)

But generated files (svcutil /sc) works with internal console test but decompiled client call (I can't modify config client - remember with .asmx works) show this message :

Failed to process the message with Action '' due to a ContractFilter mismatch in EndpointDispatcher

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a WSDL file to create a WCF service (not make a call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)

Comment: The error is caused because I imposed a name to the action, if I put the action = "" works but this means that I can use only one method because I can not set all the methods with Action = "". How can I solve?