# Offline stand-alone WSDL generation from WCF for Java client

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio, wsdl, soapui

I'm looking to generate a WSDL for offline use that someone can then use to create a service reference and generate a mock service to test their client against.  Simple, right?  Just use `svcutil` to [generate the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286657/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-all-of-the-wsdl-files-exposed-by-a-wcf-service#1951609):

```
svcutil http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc /t:metadata
```

The developer of the client can then use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to [generate a mock service](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services/1-Creating-a-MockService.html).

The trouble is the files contain references to `http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc`, so soapUI fails when trying to create the mock service with the error:

```
Error loading [http://localhost:1234/MyService?wsdl=wsdl1]:
java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;
http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc?wsdl=wsdl1, 0 -
```

- I can't [use `wsdl.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304281/create-web-service-proxy-in-visual-studio-from-a-wsdl-file#4304356), as the client is in Java, so C# files are of no use.
- I've [tried `Disco.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286657/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-all-of-the-wsdl-files-exposed-by-a-wcf-service#286710), but same result.
- The client developer cannot [add a service reference in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304281/create-web-service-proxy-in-visual-studio-from-a-wsdl-file#14360303) as they do not have Visual Studio.

I've found a reference to [download WSDL files for offline use](https://www.everit.biz/web/guest/everit-blog/-/blogs/14776), but surely there must be some easier way of generating a complete self-contained offline WSDL without installing Java or requiring a live service?

Comment: change localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Changing to 127.0.0.1 makes no difference, the developer of the client still has no local service running.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a reasonable method.  If I create a project in [soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) that references the local live WSDL, I can then right-click the endpoint and "Export Definition".  This then generates all the WSDL and XSD files without reference to the local live service which then allows offline [creation of a mock service](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-mocking/getting-started/) again using soapUI.

If there are multiple endpoints in a single service (created by the implementation of multiple service contracts in the same service) then soapUI exports the lot in one go - no need to go through each endpoint one by one.